# Making HTML element visible/invisible depending on HttpServletRequest parameter

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page, which imports another jsp. This import is wrapped into div tag.
Also I have parameter with values "true/false", which arrives from servlet as a request parameter.
I wonder what's the way to change mentioned  visibility(with the help of "style.display" attribute) using the request parameter value. The div should be visible/invisible immediately after page loads.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to display a JSP fragment (it can be a fragment that import another JSP) I would avoid to use `"style.display` attribute and I would do this:

```
<c:if test="${myVariable}">
     // import jsp, whatever you want
</c:if>
```

This is better that to import the jsp and them hide it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to be exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
<%
    if("true".equalsIgnoreCase((String)request.getAttribute("true"))){
%>
    <div class="message_div">
        // div given for style .. if div is not there too its fyn   
        //import jsp here
   </div>
<%  
   }    
%>
```